# How to know if I'm in packrat mode in R command line?

Tags: r, package-managers, packrat

If I'm using RStudio it is very easy to know if I'm in packrat mode: I just open the packages tab and click the Packrat icon. However, I don't know any commands to do it programatically or outside RStudio. Also, packrat commands such as `packrat::status()` work even if I'm not in Packrat mode.

Comment: Why isn't `packrat::status` helpful? If `packrat` has not been initiated you get the corresponding error: `Error: This project has not yet been packified. Run 'packrat::init()' to init packrat.`

Comment: I get this message only when I'm in a working directory that does not coincide with an RStudio project. When they coincide I get this message: `The following packages are referenced in your code, but are not present
in your library nor in packrat:

    Matrix
    nlme

You will need to install these packages manually, then use
packrat::snapshot() to record these packages in packrat.`

`nlme` isn't referenced nowhere in my code.

Comment: This message means that packrat is active. One of the functions you use, uses `nlme` internally. Do as the error says and you will be fine

Comment: Once I open the project in RStudio I'm able to run the code (without `nlme`) and `packrat::status()` says that everything is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You use `packrat::search_path()` to infer. See how could be done around it:

With packrat **disabled**.

```
> packrat::off()

Packrat mode off. Resetting library paths to:
- "/home/ajoe/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4"
- "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
- "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
- "/usr/lib/R/library"
>
> any(grepl("packrat", packrat::search_path()$lib.dir)) 
[1] FALSE
```

With packrat **enabled**.

```
> packrat::on()
Packrat mode on. Using library in directory:
- "~/wx/your_project_dir/packrat/lib"
>
> any(grepl("packrat", packrat::search_path()$lib.dir))
[1] TRUE
```

The same can be achieved with `.libPaths()` instead of `packrat::search_path()`.